# appstore rules for all images

Tags: xcode, app-store

i couldn't find in one place ,all the Appstore rules for the required images for an app.

1. whats the size for the image on the site(itunes ArtWork?), and the format,bits, rounded edges,etc, and **WHERE** should i put it? inside my app where the Icon is ?
2. what are the rules(sizes,format)for the 5 Appstore images,and **WHERE** should i put them?

Thanks.

please,dont give me a link for a 500 papers document to find all of it there.

Comment: And if the requirements were in a huge document?

Comment: If you're interested in asking Appstore questions without close votes you should commit to our [App Stores site exchange proposal on area51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/30702/app-stores?referrer=jcBbxTFsYbhSPTdluUKgFA2)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1- Your iTunes artwork, This is a 512 x 512 pixel 72dpi JPEG or PNG, The rounded ages will be added automatically by iTunesConnect, you shouldn't add this file to the app as you'll upload it separately when you add the app on iTunesConnect.

2- Your screenshots, 640 x 960 PNG for high resolution iPhone screenshots; 1024 x 768 PNG for iPad screenshots.

Comment: thanks. can i put only high resolution 5 screenshots, or do i need also the regular size? , they will be the same as in the appsotore? they will be portrait or landscape? cause on the store they on a landscape. do i need both ?

Comment: Recently you can only upload high resolution, so no need for the regular. You can upload it in portrait or landscape as you like.

Answer (score 1):

It isn't a 500 page document, but a short Technical Q&A:

[App Icons on iPad and iPhone](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1686/_index.html)

It's a short document listing all the required and optional icon names and sizes for both iOS devices.

And if you want a more definitive reference it's in [Icon and Images](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/IconsImages/IconsImages.html) section of the Human Interface Guidelines. This is a big document - but it's worth reading.

Comment: i have seen that, but it doesnt go over the screenShots. ALSO i couldnt understand- do i have to include all the icons needed in there? (item0 item1 etc) if my app is for iphone4 only, can i put only the icon@2x ??

Comment: I can offer a 188 page document with information regarding screenshots. [iTunes Connect Developer Guide](https://itunesconnect.apple.com/docs/iTunesConnect_DeveloperGuide.pdf) page 54++